# Correlated vs uncorrelated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to figure out how to create a statement that is using an uncorrelated subquery to write it using a correlated subquery. Here is the Oracle SQL using a uncorrelated sub query:

```
select 
    Firstname || ', '|| Lastname "Name", title, retail
from 
    Customers 
join 
    orders using (Customer#) 
join 
    orderitems using (Order#)                 
join 
    books using (Isbn)
where 
    (Customer#, retail) in (select Customer#,  max(retail)
                            from books 
                            join orderitems using (isbn) 
                            join Orders using (order#) 
                            join Customers using (Customer#)
                            group by Customer#)                 
order by  
    Firstname, Lastname, title;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally speaking, uncorrelated subqueries will perform much better than correlated subqueries.  Nevertheless, you asked for a correlated subquery that will provide the same results as your uncorrelated one.  If I understand your query correctly, you are trying to get a list of customers with the most expensive book they purchased (I'm assuming `retail` is a column on `books`).

Correlated Subquery:

```
select Firstname || ', '|| Lastname "Name", title, retail
  from Customers c 
  join orders using (Customer#) 
  join orderitems using (Order#)                 
  join books using (Isbn)
where retail = (
  select max(retail)
    from books b2 
    join orderitems using (isbn) 
    join Orders o using (order#) 
   where o.Customer# = c.Customer#
)                 
order by  Firstname, Lastname, title;
```

That query is likely to run MUCH slower than the one you have.  It will essentially perform the inner query for every row of the outer query.

If you are looking for a query that will work a bit faster, try the following:

```
with order_books as
(
  select Customer#, title, retail
    from orders 
    join orderitems using (Order#)                 
    join books b1 using (Isbn)
)
select Firstname || ', '|| Lastname "Name", ob1.title, ob1.retail
  from Customers
  join order_books ob1 using (Customer#)
  left outer join order_books ob2
    on (   ob2.Customer# = ob1.Customer# 
       and ob2.retail > ob1.retail )
 where ob2.Customer# is null             
 order by  Firstname, Lastname, ob1.title;
```

This query doesn't contain subqueries, and it ought to be much faster than either of the queries above.  It uses an outer join to look for `ob2` rows that have a greater retail value than the current `ob1` row.  Then, it uses the WHERE clause to only return the `ob1` rows that don't have any matching `ob2` rows.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works and helped me understand the difference in doing them both.